# How to make and connect the Java swing program that has uploading, setting header and footer report

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I am developing an application in *Java Swing*. I am using *JasperReports* and *iReport* in my application.

I have successfully made the connection between *JasperReports* and database and also loaded the *jrxml* file.

My Question is that after completing the development of my application I want that applications's users be able to set their logo, can change their header and footers. One way i can do this is by creating a User Interface that is a *JFrame* which has uploading image option + change the headers and footers of the report. But how do I connect my *JFrame* components with a *JR* report so that changes made in components of my *JFrame* should get reflected in report?

[image: This is the frame i want to make any selection or changes made into this should get reflected on Jasper Report]

Comment: Your question is not really clear. How do you have the images set up in the report (i.e. hardcoded path, you pass in the image bytes as a parameter, etc)? Where are you storing the uploaded images the customer selects?

Comment: Yes, but to where? Is it in your database, is it on a file server somewhere? For that matter do you generate the report on the server and send it to the client, or do you generate it in the client?

Comment: Yes i am saving the logo in database and it is client application and not the client server application

Comment: Sir i am waiting for ur reply

Comment: @ZaheerBoovaji You can use *JasperReports API* or *DynamicJasper API* for example

Comment: @ZaheerBoovaji You question is quite large to provide an adequate answer. As Alex suggested you should take a look at DynamicJasper in this particular case. You would be able to do most of what you want with out a JRXML and through java code.

Comment: Sir could you please provide an example code and the steps to use this Dynamic Jasper as because i am new to reports

Comment: The [ImageBannerReportTest](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/xref-test/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test/ImageBannerReportTest.html) example they provide a good bit of what you need. Other than that just go through their [Getting Started](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/getting-started/) section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the meaning of "upload" is saving the image in the hard disk of server computer in a specific path then saving this path in the database.

1. Convert the uploaded image into [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

   ```
   String imgPath = "[path_of_uploaded_image_here]";
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imgPath));
   ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ImageIO.write(image, "gif", os);
   InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
   ```
2. Pass the converted image as a parameter to the jasperreport.(here the param name is ENTITY_IMAGE)
3. Inside the iReport, create a parameter. Data type of this parameter should be `java.io.InputStream`
4. Drag an image. Go the image properties. Under the image properties, change the value of Expression Class as `java.io.InputStream` then the Image Expression as $P{ENTITY_IMAGE}.